# Is Amnesia available for free?

Tags: software-installation, games

How do we download or install the game *Amnesia*? Do we have to buy it or is it free?
(I'm running Ubuntu 12.04.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot play it for free. You can get it for $20 [on Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/57300/), which you can find in the Software Center as [steam-launcher](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/steam-launcher/) [image: Install steam-launcher]. It is also available for purchase [from the Humble Store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/p/amnesia_thedarkdescent_storefront) and [from Desura](http://www.desura.com/games/amnesia-the-dark-descent). All three include the Linux version, which works on Ubuntu.

The only thing that's free of charge is [**the demo**](http://www.amnesiagame.com/#demo) ([demo-only torrent](http://gameupdates.org/details.php?id=4315), [demo-only HTTP download](http://fricpub.s3.amazonaws.com/demo/amnesia_tdd_demo_1.0.1.sh)).

Comment: So, you can't get it for free?

Comment: The only thing that's free is the demo http://www.amnesiagame.com/#demo.